# Create a vector: c(1,2,4,2,2) and use rank variable to return c(1,2,5,2,2)

Tags: r, vector, rank

I would like to create a vector:
`c(1,2,4,2,2)`
And use rank variable to return:
`c(1,2,5,2,2)`
How do I use rank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `?rank` help page for options, specifically the `ties.method=` paramter. Specifically the output you want can be generated with `ties.method="min"`

```
rank(c(1,2,4,2,2), ties.method = "min")
# [1] 1 2 5 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `min_rank` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
min_rank(c(1,2,4,2,2))
#[1] 1 2 5 2 2
```